# Passing a properties file in XML,Spring

Tags: xml, spring, properties

I want to Autowire my service in Spring with XMl.
The class I want to autowire looks like this:

```
public class Service{
     public Service(String type,Properties property){....}    
    ....
}
```

I have an instance of this object in my controller.

```
@Autowired
protected Service service;
```

So now I wan't to instantiate this object in my xml file. This worked before I started to use the properties inside my constructor, so everything is configured the right way. But now I've added the properties Obect, I don't know how to pass them to the contructor. This is how it looks now:

```
<bean id="service" class="service.service">
        <constructor-arg > 
            <value>MYSQL</value>
        </constructor-arg> 
        <constructor-arg > 
            <property name="url">jdbc:....</property>
        <property name="user">myUsername</property>
            <property name="password">mypass</property>
        </constructor-arg> 
    </bean>
```

The first parameter works (MYSQL), but I don(t know how to create a properties Object in XML and pass that to my service. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `util:properties` and pass it as a `ref` to constructor. I have not tested it, but should give you the idea.

```
<util:properties id="myproperties" location="classpath:/myproperties.properties" />

<bean id="service" class="service.service">
        <constructor-arg > 
            <value>MYSQL</value>
        </constructor-arg> 
        <constructor-arg ref="myproperties"/>            

    </bean>
```

Comment: Will try it tomorrow, thank you for the fast reply. Will select it as right answer once it works. Thank you!

Comment: Where should I place the .properties file if I may ask? Under the WEB-INF folder? Because that folder isn't under the classpath I think

Comment: I've added and config folder under WEB-INF and added it to the classpath and stored my properties file in there. Is this best practice?

Comment: Usually if you use a maven structure, it will be under src/main/resources (or a folder under there) which will eventually go to WEB-INF/classes (folder under that) folder. If you not using maven, configure it go under `WEB-INF/classes` which will be in class path.